# Как получить информацию по чеку из qr-кода?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, qr

Есть такая строчка:
`t=20171206T120600&s=522.00&fn=8710000100756670&i=53519&fp=120068872&n=1`

Как мне в скрипте получить из нее данные?
Мне нужно из нее получить информацию о покупках и др.
Есть множество онлайн ресурсов, но мне нужно в скрипте как-то забрать данные из этой строки.

Comment: Скорее всего там записан владелец, id операции, а подробности о покупке хранятся в отдельном месте

Answer (score 3):

Вы можете начать изучать этот вопрос с этой статьи: https://habr.com/post/358966/

Нужно будет пройти аутентификацию (basic) в API и отправить следующий запрос (для ваших данных) на сервер налоговой:

```
https://proverkacheka.nalog.ru:9999/v1/inns/*/kkts/*/fss/8710000100756670/tickets/53519?fiscalSign=120068872&sendToEmail=no
```